# Why is the export menu malformed in IE8

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/FX5yy/)

Works well in Chrome and Firefox but, when I click on the Download text in IE, 
the menu appears malformed.  any idea why? here is the bit of code that may need
adjustment.

```
exporting: {
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exportButton: {
                text: 'Download',
                // Use only the download related menu items from the default context button
                menuItems: Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.splice(2)
            },
            printButton: {
                text: 'Print',
                onclick: function () {
                    this.print();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I advice to use stable version 3.0.4 instead of git beta version.

Comment: @ Sebastian Bochan The version is 3.0.4.

Comment: Indeed looks like a bug, reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2182